# How to import Svelte component into vanilla JS project, without adding Svelte as a dependency to that parent project?

Tags: javascript, npm, es6-modules, svelte-component

As the title implies: I am looking for a way to import a Svelte component into a project that "does not know what Svelte it" (i.e. does not use Svelte as a dependency).

Imagine making a npm package that contains a Svelte component and then installing that package in one or several projects. The projects that install that package do not need to add Svelte as a dependency. The package is self-contained that way.

In this specific case I cannot, however, use npm to expose my Svelte component to the projects that need it. I was thinking more along the lines of simply sending the code to those that need it, so they can import it as a module (maybe naive...), but I would not know how to make that meet the dependency requirement described above.

I am looking for a similarly self-contained way of making my Svelte component available to projects.

Any ideas? Ty.

Comment: npm and a public package repository is not the only way to install a package. Easiest solution for you would be a private package repository, but you can do all the work manually without a package manager and simply copy files into `node_modules` if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: It might be possible to do what you're looking for with SvelteKit's [component packaging](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/packaging) feature (referenced from Svelte's [compiler](https://svelte.dev/docs#compile-time) documentation), using the `@sveltejs/package` package.

Comment: Ty. I'll keep an eye on the component packaging feature.

Comment: Think this could be what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75895650/537098

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Svelte builds to a web component I don't think it's possible. Many npm packages are targeted at the Frameworks they're made for....
You could make your package using Vanilla JS or TypeScript and it'll be installable everywhere.
A new JavaScript framework called [Astro](https://astro.build/) is looking to merge all the frameworks, you could check it out.

Comment: Because Svelte is a compiler, my reasoning was that it might be possible. I already went ahead and started a vanilla JS module for my component. But Svelte has some great features that I'll miss.